# Shortcode atts for WP Query args

Tags: shortcode

I need to create a shortcode for display CPT posts. I want to add an atts that print the number of posts_per_page I need in the args for Wp_query.

But If I use

```
[short_events number=5]
```

it prints only one post. Where I'm Wrong?

```
function dis_short_events($atts, $content = null){

    ob_start();
    $numero = extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'number' => '-1',
     ), $atts));

    $args =array(
        'post_type'=>'eventi',
        'posts_per_page' => $numero

    );
}

add_shortcode('short_events', 'dis_short_events');
```

Comment: The shortcode parameters are contained in the first parameter passed to the shortcode function (`$atts`), so you could use `$atts['number']` to get the "number" parameter. But you extracted the parameters (see [`extract()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)), so you could also use `$number`. So you *don't* use `$numero`, but `$number`.

Answer (score 0):

It's typically best practice to not extract your shortcode atts.

```
function dis_short_events($atts, $content = null){

ob_start();
$numero = shortcode_atts(array(
    'number' => '-1',
 ), $atts);

$args =array(
    'post_type'=>'eventi',
    'posts_per_page' => $numero['number']

);
```